# multiple gravity forms validation with show/hide div using radio button

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress

I am having trouble using 2 gravity forms on the same page. To start off, each form is in a hidden "div", a user must select from 3 radio buttons which shows/hides the other form. This part works, *however* if validation fails, the page refreshes and the form is hidden. The user has to re-click on the same radio to see why the validation has failed. I've also set gravity forms to use ajax mode, but that doesn't fix the problem.

This is what my JavaScript looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

        jQuery(".cdiv").hide();

        jQuery("input[name=contact_type]").change(function() {
            var _div_id = jQuery(this).val();
            jQuery(".cdiv").hide('slow');
            jQuery("#"+_div_id).show('slow');
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

The HTML looks something like this (I removed the forms to keep the html short)

```
<input type="radio" name="contact_type" value="c1" /> Careers <br />
<input type="radio" name="contact_type" value="c2" /> Partner with us <br />
<input type="radio" name="contact_type" value="c3" /> Media Inquiries <br />

<div class="cdiv" id="c1">
[career info here]
</div>

<div class="cdiv" id="c2">
form 1 loads here
</div>


<div class="cdiv" id="c3">
form 2 loads here
</div>
```

Your help and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are STATELESS - when they load (or reload) they have no idea what their previous state was.

It's up to YOU to restore state, therefore you must record this state somewhere. This is typically stored in a URL hash or a cookie.

How this should work with a URL hash (you need to write the code to do this):

When the user clicks one of the radio buttons, you set `document.location.hash` to a known value, such as "b1".

Then when the page reloads, you look at the current value of `document.location.hash` (using JS) and if the value is "b1" you know the user pressed radio button #1. Then your script shows the appropriate panel.